# Sharing does not show the thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, share

When i share something from my [website](http://youthdrum.com/) to a social media or bookmarking site, it doesn't show the thumbnail.

Can anyone tell me the exact reason for that?

You can have a look at the source code of my website.

Comment: You can ask this in the WordPress forum http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's actually showing a thumbnail (atleast on facebook) but its using a defualt "no image" picture on your site. 
http://youthdrum.com/wp-content/themes/mesocolumn/images/noimage.png

You can replace that image with your thumbnail of choice but it would also replace the image wherever its being used on your site. But since you are using wordpress the easiest and simple way is using this plugin, it'd be very useful in your case.
http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-facebook-share-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use different plugins, you can manually specify what images are shown in social media sites.

For example, for Facebook you need to specify which image is going to be shown. How are you going to do this depends on type of embeded Facebook like plugins.

Typically, most of the people are putting specified info in the code. Facebook is using technology called *Open Graph*, so you need to put special meta info in your code, for example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yoursite.com/image.jpg" />
```

So now Facebook knows that image.jpg should be placed in your stream.

**But what if you're using integrated Wordpress thumbnail system?** How you can get Wordpress thumbnail URL on given single page?

Put this code into **functions.php**:

```
 function get_fbimage() {
 $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '', '' );
 if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ) {
 $fbimage = $src[0];
 } else {
 global $post, $posts;
 $fbimage = '';
 $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',
 $post->post_content, $matches);
 $fbimage = $matches [1] [0];
 }
 if(empty($fbimage)) {
 $fbimage = "http://www.gogirlfinance.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/logo.jpg";
 }
 return $fbimage;     }
```

Then you can simply gain thumbnail URL by typing:

```
<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>
```

So then you should put into **header.php** this:

```
<?php if ( is_single ()) : ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_fbimage(); ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```